# Create custom html dropdown that gets SharePoint 2016 managed metadata values

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

I'm setting up a custom html form that uses javascript to add items into a SharePoint list. I need to get a list of terms from SharePoint 2016 managed metadata. Its a list of terms for office locations. I want to get these values and show them in a custom html drop down. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

We can use the SharePoint web service to get the terms from managed metadata.

```
/_vti_bin/TaxonomyClientService.asmx
```

Or we can use JSOM in SharePoint to achieve it.

```
var termsList = "Terms: \n"
function showTerms(termSetId) {
    //We need to load and populat the matching Term Set first.
    var termSetEnum = termSets.getEnumerator();
    while (termSetEnum.moveNext()) {
        var currentTermSet = termSetEnum.get_current();
        if (currentTermSet.get_id() == termSetId) {
            //If termSet Matches, then get all terms.
            context.load(currentTermSet);
            context.executeQueryAsync(
            function () {
            //Load terms
            var terms = currentTermSet.get_terms();
            context.load(terms);
            context.executeQueryAsync(
                function () {
                    var termsEnum = terms.getEnumerator();
                    while (termsEnum.moveNext()) {
                        var currentTerm = termsEnum.get_current();
                        var termName = currentTerm.get_name();
                        var termId = currentTerm.get_id();
                        termsList += termName + ": " + termId;

                        //Check if term has child terms
                        if (currentTerm.get_termsCount() > 0) {
                            //Term has sub terms.
                            recursiveTerms(currentTerm, 1);
                        }
                        alert(termList);
                    }
                },
                function () {
                //failure to load terms.
                });
            },
            function () {
            //failure to load current term set
            });
            break;
        }
    }
}
function recursiveTerms(currentTerm, nestedLoop) {
    //Loop count for formatting purpose.
    var loop = nestedLoop + 1;
    //Get Term child terms
    var terms = currentTerm.get_terms();
    context.load(terms);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            var termsEnum = terms.getEnumerator();
            while (termsEnum.moveNext()) {
                var newCurrentTerm = termsEnum.get_current();
                var termName = newCurrentTerm.get_name();
                termId = newCurrentTerm.get_id();

                //Tab Out format.
                for (var i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
                    termsList += "\t";
                }
                termsList += termName + ": " + termId;
                //Check if term has child terms.
                if (currentTerm.get_termsCount() > 0) {
                    //Term has sub terms.
                    recursiveTerms(newCurrentTerm, loop);
                }
            }
        },
        function () {
        //failure to load terms
        }
    );
}
```

The following articles for your reference.

[Using jQuery to return the Managed Metadata Term GUID](https://spandps.com/2011/03/02/using-jquery-to-return-the-managed-metadata-term-guid-sp2010-sharepoint-in/)

[Accessing Taxonomy Term Store with JSOM](https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/accessing-taxonomy-term-store-with-jsom/)